# Cloud Automation Manager - offline install via helm CLI

Tags: cloud-automation-manager

I recently hitted an issue where I could not use the ICP GUI to install Cloud Automation Manager, but yet I really needed to select the "optimize for offline" option since it was an air-gapped environment.  I reviewed the knowledge center but I did not find the way to use this option via helm CLI.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can add the following set to your Cloud Automation Manager helm install command (2.1.0.3 FP1 or newer release)

```
--set global.offline=true
```

for example

```
helm install ibm-cam-3.1.0.tgz --name cam --namespace services --set global.iam.deployApiKey=[Api key for service-deploy] --set global.audit=<true | false> --set global.offline=true --tls
```

We will also add this to our installation parameters page shortly as well here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2L37_3.1.0.0/cam_installation_parameters.html

Thanks for your question!

Answer (score 0):

Please also take a look at this recent blog post in the Dev Works area:
https://developer.ibm.com/cloudautomation/2018/10/18/ibm-cloud-automation-manager-3-1-delivers-improved-offline-installation-experience/